# Rails Puma inside of Docker Instance stops responding from inactivity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, docker, google-compute-engine

I have a Docker file which correctly builds and runs a Rails Application. Everything works. As long as I keep sending traffic to the instance, it works. However, if I leave it idle for more than a couple of minutes, it stops responding. On the server, wget localhost: just gets stuck.

```
wget localhost:8081
--2014-01-28 18:34:23--  http://localhost:8081/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8081... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

However, it works just fine when I first boot the instance and will work for hours if I consistently send traffic.

The Rails App is 3.2.14 with Puma. I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy, but this is definitely a problem actually getting the request into the box.  As far as I can see from the log, the request never hits Puma or Rails.

UPDATE: So it appears to be sporadic-it'll start taking request, and then stop taking requests. It'll be idle, I'll ping it-it won't work. Then maybe 10 minutes later I go to access it-works. 10 minutes more of idle, it's down. No idea if this helps.

UPDATE: This appears to be a GCE issue, as running the same on AWS had no issues. Opened up a docker issue: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/3852

Any idea on a cause or where to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several fixes to the GCE image, this is no longer an issue.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm having the same issue!